# Ajax Post return type instead of value c# mvc 4

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

i have this problem.

my function is this

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/controller/CreateList",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            traditional: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(myvar),
            success: function (returnArray) {
            }
.....
```

in my controller i have this action:

```
public int[] CreateList(List<ERoleCommission> erolecommission){
        List<int> intList= new List<int>();
        ...//populate the List
        return  intList.ToArray();
}
```

with debug i see that intList has filled with the right value, so it isn't a c# error,
after calling this action from controller the debug return to js function and returnArray = "System.Int32[]", it contains only type.
why?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing your controller/action I only guess, but my first guess would be that you forget to JSON-encode the data before you return it as an ActionResult from your action. Try something like this in your action:

```
public JsonResult YourAction() {
    // ... do stuff
    var yourArrayOfData = CreateList(yourListOfData);
    return Json(yourArrayOfData);
}
```

Comment: yes, it is the right answer, so when i try to pass a non primitive type i need to encode it to json type?

Comment: @NinoEmma That's right, you need to return a [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.108).aspx) from your action, and calling `Json()` will take your array and turn it into a `JsonResult` that you can then return.